# UIActivityIndicatorView: how it works?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiactivityindicatorview

I don't quite understand, why it doesn't freeze when main thread is doing something heavy? All UI work must be done in main thread in redraw cycle. Does it use layer animation?

Answer (score 1):

Every UI work should be done in main thread? Really every?

On OS X there is an `NProgressIndicator` (similar to `UIProgressIndicator`, related to `UIActivityIndicator`) which has the same problem, but is older. It has an explicit property `usesThreadedAnimation` to solve this problem.

I assume that this is always `YES` for `UIActivityIndicator` and `UIProgressIndicator`.

Answer (score -1):

> An activity indicator is a spinning wheel that indicates a task is in
>   the midst of being processed. If an action takes a noticeable and
>   indeterminate amount of time to process—such as a CPU-intensive task
>   or connecting to a network—you should display an activity indicator to
>   give assurance to the user that your app is not stalled or frozen.
>
> Making Activity Indicators Accessible
>
> Activity indicators are accessible by default. The default
>   accessibility trait for an activity indicator is User Interaction
>   Enabled.

Comment: thanks, cap) my question is about internal implementation of UIActivityIndicatorView